# Problema haciendo solicitud de firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, local-storage

Cuando intento descargar algo del servicio storage de firebase, y le paso como parámetro al método `getReferenceFromUrl` de la clase `StorageReference`, me arroja el siguiente error:

> ```
> com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: 
> Object does not exist at location accents android
> ```

Sin embargo, esto solo me ocurre cuando el parámetro que envío posee tildes

Ej:

```
Víspera
Paráclesis
```

etc...

Pero por otro lado, cuando envio como parametro con `ó` me arroja correctamente el resultado.

He intentado codificar con `URLEncode` o `URLDecoder` el string que paso, pero de igual manera me arroja el mismo error.

Alguna idea?

SOLUCIONADO

lo hice uttilizando esta funcion

Normalizer
            .normalize(fileName, Normalizer.Form.NFD);

la cual es la equivalente en android a como se hace en ios q es : 
(NSString *)decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping Equivalent to NFD in Java/Android

Comment: por favor agregá la url a la que tratas de acceder y el codigo.